# Unable to create geometric network. Feature classes unavailable

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, geometric-network

When I try to create a geometric network 4 of my 9 feature classes are 'unavailable'. When I click on the 'unavailable' button it states that each feature class has an 'Invalid 'Enabled' field type' (see image below).

[image]

This problem has me stumped as I can't find much information on this particular error. Does anyone know what this error is referring to or how to rectify it?

Comment: I'm just fumbling around with Google results here, but it looks like those feature classes either don't have a field called Enabled, or the datatype of the field they do have is not the correct data type.

Comment: Do feature classes that are part of a geometric network have to have a field called enabled? Or is is it a type of field associated with geometric networks?

Comment: That's where I'm unclear - this isn't really something I've worked with before. I think that *within* the network, [yes they do](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002r00000027000000). But I would also think that the field would be added as part of creating the network, leading me to believe that perhaps those classes already had an Enabled field for some reason and it was set to the wrong data type. But that's all speculation on my part.

Comment: Alright, thanks anyway. I was hoping the solution would be something obvious I wasn't aware of but it looks like I'll have to take a close look.

Comment: @Geord359 I guess that more details about your data structure, i.e. fields type, in particular for those feature classes that cause the problem would be valuable for disant answer to come. In addition, description of the network parameters would be helpful, e.g. did you use one or more of those layers as source or sinks, weights, etc. Did you use simple junctions or complex edges. Pictures would do the job...

Comment: p.s if you can upload some sample data it might be possible to reproduce your error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Any feature classes that are part of a geometric network have to have a field called 'Enabled', The  'Enabled' field need to be with the  'Enabled'  domain**.

Any feature in a geometric network can be enabled or disabled. An enabled feature allows flow to pass through it, while a disabled feature does not. Disabling features allows you to treat them as if they were disconnected from the network without actually removing the topological connections that they have to other features in the network. By default, all features in a geometric network are enabled when you create the network.

Comment: Your spot on Geog. Unbeknownst to me the dataset in question had been used in a geometric network before I started using it. So it had an enabled field.

Comment: @Geord359. It's a bit uncleared from the answer what one should do to handle such a problem. Arcmap does not prevent the re-creation of a geometric network with data that was used to such a task before. Yet 'Enabled' field should be of a certain datatype, usually boolean or short int. Can you speicfy what you've done to make it work?

Comment: @dof1985 In this case it was the re-use of data that had already been part of a geometric network that caused the problem. The feature classes that I used were a copy of data used by someone else in my organisation. I did not know that they had previously used it to construct a geometric network. Hence, they had created an 'enabled' field that I was unaware of. I have since removed this field and created a geometric network successfully using the above feature classes.